# Replacement Function

Tags: r, function, replace

> x <- c(22,33,45)
>
> erase <- function(x, value)  {
>
> x[!x %in% value]
>
> }
>
> erase(x, 45)

it prints output as 22, 33

Can anybody describe how this code removes 45 from vector x?

let say  vector  x <- c(33, 22, 45)

In the earlier code the function body says, take index of x and inside the index don't keep the value matched with x. If say the value is 45 and it removed from x inside the indexing then in outer of indexing i.e.  x [ ] how it restoring the 33 and 22 and producing output 33 22 as it is index values. I'm little bit confused with this function, how actually it keeping the index 1 and 2 as 33 and 22.

why not it returning x[33,22] which provides NA values but actually it taking the values like x[1,2] excluding the 33 at 3rd index position.

May be I'm not getting it properly. Can anyone please elaborate how the code is producing 33 and 22 as output?

**** This code is for R programming language.

Answer (score 2):

see `?'%in%'`.

The vector `x %in% 45` checks whether each element of `x` is in `45` and records `TRUE` if it is, else `FALSE` (since `45` is a single value, this is the same as `x == 45`).

So `x %in% 45 == c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)`

Then the `!` operator reverses logical values, so

`! x %in% 45 == c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)`

When you subset by entering a logical vector in `[]`, the values of the vector whose indexes correspond to the value `FALSE` in the logical vector are removed. In this case, only `45` has an index (3) whose value in the logical vector is `FALSE`, so it is removed.